# Need help regarding Mapbox markers

Tags: javascript, jquery, logic, coordinates, mapbox

I am using mapbox and I am trying to hide a marker until the building itself is clicked using JS. I've tried setting event listeners on my whole map but it will only pop up if the exact coordinates are clicked. Because a building can be of varied size, how would I implement a click function that makes the marker appear when an actual building is clicked and not the coordinates?